# Swagger 3.x funciona com .Net 4.7?

Tags: .net, asp.net, swagger

estou tentando criar exemplos de Resposta e de Entrada pelo Swagger mas não estou obtendo sucesso.

Até agora, o máximo que consegui foi criar o MOCK de entrada da requisição, os de saída não estou conseguindo.

Segue código:

```
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(PessoaModel), typeof(EntradaExample))]
[SwaggerResponseExample(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, typeof(BadRequestResponseExample))] 
[SwaggerResponseExample(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, typeof(InternalServerErrorResponseExample))]
```

Uma outra dúvida que eu tenho é se o .Net 4.7 tem suporte para o Swagger-ui 3.x

Obrigado